# immutable local maven repository

Tags: java, maven, clojure, repository

When using `lein install` or e.g. `boot pom jar install`, a Clojure project is packed inside a jar and installed to the local maven repository. Which is stored as a folder structure of several jars for instance under `~/.m2`

These installations are mutable, meaning a project of a specific version (e.g. `0.1.0`) can be overridden by calling the same command after something has changed inside the project but without the version being changed.

When pushing to a public repository such as clojars, this is not possible. There I guess only `*-SNAPSHOT` versions one can override existing pushs.

Wouldn't it be desirable to have this immutability already in a local repository? Are there ways to archive this?

Comment: Why would this be desirable? Also, incidentally, Clojars SNAPSHOT versions are more immutable than you might think; see [this discussion](https://github.com/clojars/clojars-web/issues/537) for more details.

Comment: Interesting link. What lead me to this point is the thought, that making a project immutable should not implicitly mean making it public to everyone. Of course making something immutable for oneself may sound a bit silly but maybe it can be helpful sometimes. But what if more people are involved. Ok, I see - in this case one might better setup a remote repo only accessible to a group of people.

Comment: maybe it's really tow questions: if it makes sense and if/how it's possible technically.

Answer (score 2):

I run a copy of [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/download-oss-sonatype) an an AWS instance for this purpose, though it woule make sense to run it on your own computer. Most of the benefits (except protection against the loss of this computer) with lower latency. The price is right as well.